# Конвертация строки в дату (PyQT5)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, дата

Доброе утро!
У меня есть код, который забирает данные из JSON в апи. Там много разных данных, но в настоящий момент достаю только title и две даты. Даты из JSON забираются в строковом формате, а мне же, для использования в pyqt5, нужно конвертировать строки в qdate.
Есть вот такой код и, насколько я понимаю, конвертирование можно провести прямо в этом классе.

```
class ModelStructure:
    def __init__(self, id, created, title, start_date, end_date):
        self.title = title
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, data):
        return cls(**data)
```

Спасибо за внимание

Comment: `a = QtCore.QDate(2018, 11, 19);
print(a)` вот вам перевод в `QDate`

Comment: У строк разный формат данных, приведите в вопрос пример вашей строки. Кст, есть специальный метод получения даты из строки: QDate::fromString http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-1 и, дополнительно, у QDate есть конструктор, который принимает 3 параметра: год, месяц и день

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У [QDate](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qdate.html) есть статичный метод [QDate.fromString(date_str, date_format)](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-1):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate


class ModelStructure:
    def __init__(self, id, created, title, start_date, end_date):
        self.title = title
        self.start_date = QDate.fromString(start_date, "yyyy/MM/dd")
        self.end_date = QDate.fromString(end_date, "yyyy/MM/dd")

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, data):
        return cls(**data)


data = {
    'id': 1, 'created': True,
    'title': 'About',
    'start_date': '2018/01/01', 'end_date': '2019/01/01'
}

item = ModelStructure.from_json(data)
print(item.start_date)  # PyQt5.QtCore.QDate(2018, 1, 1)
print(item.end_date)    # PyQt5.QtCore.QDate(2019, 1, 1)
```